# More than 3 line email form submission response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have seen a lot of form email scripts, but the easiest ones only have 3 lines `Name`, `Email` and `Message`.

Is there a way I can add more to the script to include more lines in them?

Answer (score 1):

You should [look here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_mailapp) for exampels of all that you can do, but if your looking for a way to layout an email with paragraph breaks.  Here's a method for you to display a more complex body of the message:

```
 var body = "Dear User,";
  body += "\n\nWe have received your Email.";
  body += "\n\nWe need samples of your work (scripts, portfolio, photos, DVDs) to complete your file.";
  body += "\n\nPlease either mail or email your samples to us.  Our contact information is below.";
  body += "\n\nPlease do not hesitate to contact us if you have any further questions.";
  body += "\n\nThank you,";
```

The `\n\n` is the way of returning twice.  You can also use `\n` to simply return once.
And you can use other advanced arguments like the following:

```
var ccList = "me@me.com";
var mailReplyTo = "me@me.com";
var emailName = "ME!";
var optAdvancedArgs = {replyTo:mailReplyTo, bcc:ccList, name:emailName};

MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, optAdvancedArgs);
```